# KinectStatus-Connected Disconnected not getting displayed dont know why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I want to display the kinect status-Connected or disconnected and the Device Connection ID.
Connection ID is getting displayed,but Status is not getting displayed in Textblock
My code is-

mainwindow.xaml.cs-

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    KinectSensor sensor;
    private MainWindowViewModel viewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        this.viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;

    }


    void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case KinectStatus.Connected:
                txtBlckStatus.Text = "Connected";


                 break;
            case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
                 txtBlckStatus.Text = "Disconnected";

                 break;

        }
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count > 0)
        {
            this.sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
            KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;

            this.StartSensor();
            this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
            this.sensor.DepthStream.Enable();
            this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Sensor Connected!!");
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    private void StartSensor()
    {
        if(this.sensor!=null && !this.sensor.IsRunning)
        {
            this.sensor.Start();
            SetKinectInfo();

        }
    }

    private void StopSensor()
    {
        if (this.sensor != null && !this.sensor.IsRunning)
        {
            this.sensor.Stop();

        }
    }

    private void SetKinectInfo()
    {
        if(this.sensor!=null)
        {
            this.viewModel.ConnectionID = this.sensor.DeviceConnectionId;
        }
    }

}
```

mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="KinectInfoBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Status:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtBlckStatus"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Connection ID"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ConnectionID}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Stop"  Margin="179,81,179,42" x:Name="StopSensorButton"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

mainwindowviewmodel.cs--to display the changing connection id

```
namespace KinectInfoBox
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _connectionIDValue;
        public string ConnectionID
        {
            get { return _connectionIDValue; }
            set 
            {
                if(this._connectionIDValue!=value)
                {
                    this._connectionIDValue = value;
                    this.OnNotifyPropertyChange("ConnectionID");
                }
            }
        }
        public void OnNotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if(this.PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                   this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this,newPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you try to debug and see if the event listener KinectSensors_StatusChanged is called ? You'll be able to check the e.Status value

Comment: yes,thanks for the very much late reply,and i already came up with the solution 2 days before

Comment: Don't forget to share it so that other user can have the solution in the future

Comment: Florent Gz do you have any idea how to make real virtual trial room using kinect?? If yes then please help how should i start and all??

Comment: I just don't get the real virtual trial room concept

Comment: In real virtual trial room 3d clothes are mapped on the real person,do you have any idea of making this using kinect wpf c# xna?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is perfectly allright,actually the kinect is initially connected with the system,so there is no state changed,but when you unplug the kinect then the status change even is triggered,so you will see the status disconnected in the textblock and when you connect ity again the status connected will get displayed there.